# Iterator on vector error for operands "=" and "!="

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, iterator

```
using namespace std;
    vector<IDrawable*>::const_iterator itDrawable;
    for(itDrawable= scene.getDrawables().begin(); itDrawable!=scene.getDrawables().end();itDrawable++){
        IDrawable *drawable =(*itDrawable);
        drawable->draw();
    }
```

This code is passing me the error:

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type no match for 'operator!='
>   (operand types are '`std::vector<IDrawable*>::const_iterator` {aka
>   `__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<IDrawable* const*, std::vector<IDrawable*> >`}' and '`std::vector<const
>   IDrawable*>::const_iterator` {aka `__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const
>   IDrawable* const*, std::vector<const IDrawable*> >`}')

And

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type no match for 'operator='
>   (operand types are '`std::vector<IDrawable*>::const_iterator` {aka
>   `__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<IDrawable* const*, std::vector<IDrawable*> >`}' and '`std::vector<const
>   IDrawable*>::const_iterator` {aka `__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const
>   IDrawable* const*, std::vector<const IDrawable*> >`}')

I have looked these up and i should have something to do with the const_iterator ?
yet my `scene.getDrawables()` looks like:

```
const std::vector<const IDrawable*>& getDrawables() const {
        return drawables;
    }
```

So the iterator should be a const_iterator right ?
I have no clue what has to change...

Comment: You don't see any difference between the type `getDrawables()` returns and the type you're declaring the iterators to be?

Comment: lolz, no i did not haha :p

Comment: No, this is the only getter...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your

```
const std::vector<const IDrawable*>& getDrawables() const
```

returns a const reference to a vector of `const IDrawable*` pointers. However your

```
vector<IDrawable*>::const_iterator itDrawable;
```

declares a `const_iterator` to a vector of different type (`IDrawable*`, not `const IDrawable*`). Either change the definition to `vector<const IDrawable*>::const_iterator itDrawable;` or simply use `auto` to declare the iterator in your `for` loop,

```
for(auto itDrawable= scene.getDrawables().cbegin(); ...)
```

Answer (score 2):

The formatting of your question hides the real problem, but you used:

```
vector<IDrawable*>::const_iterator itDrawable;
```

where you should have used

```
vector<const IDrawable*>::const_iterator iDrawable;
```

Likewise, you then need

```
const IDrawable *drawable =...
```

instead of

```
IDrawable *drawable =...
```

All this due to the fact that you have a `std::vector<const IDrawable*>`.